# javascript multidimensional array out of mysql table - dont know whats that kind of Object Object

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, object

I am trying to get my data out of a mysql table and work with those data in Javascript.
I'm home in php and there are many differences to javascript :( and theres my problem I do think in php and need to understand javascript :)

ok heres the question:
I get from my php script the data out of the table in thsi format: used

```
while($Search=mysql_fetch_assoc($abfrage)){
  $data[] = $Search;
 }

 echo json_encode( $data );
```

and get this data:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [date] => 2017-12-01 [time] => 00:00:00  [active] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [date] => 2017-12-02 [time] => 00:00:00 [active] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [date] => 2017-12-08 [time] => 00:00:00 [active] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [date] => 2017-12-09 [time] => 00:00:00 [active] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [date] => 2017-12-15 [time] => 00:00:00 [active] => 1 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 6 [date] => 2017-12-16 [time] => 00:00:00 [active] => 1 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 7 [date] => 2017-12-22 [time] => 20:00:00 [active] => 1 ) )
```

so I used then javascript to get an array or object or whatever this is. I dont really know much about objects-.

```
var myArr = JSON.parse
```

to get an array out of this data:

```
[[object Object] {
   active: "1",
   date: "2017-12-01",
   id: "1",
  time: "00:00:00"
}]
```

what does this 
[[object Object] 
mean is this an array or an object and how do I work with it?

My goal is to see if there is a date inside the data which comes from the database and if yes check if there is also a time set to this date.

I've made an example at jsbin for testing but I dont know how to go on to receive the data I want:
http://jsbin.com/wariparoce/edit?html,js,console,output

Thanks for all your time and patience :)

Stev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing  to

```
 myArr.[0].active;
 myArr.[0].date;
 .....
```

this should return  the element in idenx 0 of the field active, date ,,

this mean that you obtain an array ( 0 index based)  of object with struct like you PHP assocative array .. where the key  in PHP is the key name  in JSOn  )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. After decoding the JSON string, you have an array, myArr. Just access the items directly:

```
var myArr = JSON.parse('[
    {"id":"1","date":"2017-12-01","time":"00:00:00","active":"1"},
    {"id":"2","date":"2017-12-02","time":"00:00:00","active":"1"},
    {"id":"3","date":"2017-12-08","time":"00:00:00","active":"1"},
    {"id":"4","date":"2017-12-09","time":"00:00:00","active":"1"},
    {"id":"5","date":"2017-12-15","time":"00:00:00","active":"1"},
    {"id":"6","date":"2017-12-16","time":"00:00:00","active":"1"},
    {"id":"7","date":"2017-12-22","time":"20:00:00","active":"1"}
]');

var gew_datum="2017-12-08";

for(var i = 0;i < myArr.length;i++) {
  if(gew_datum == myArr[i]['date']){
    console.log(i + ") date: " + myArr[i]["date"] + ", time: " + myArr[i]["time"] + ", active: " + myArr[i]["active"]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both so much that did the trick - I was running around in the "result" (u can see at jsbin) thing which I created afterwards to find out if the given date is in the array or not - and there I didn't get the data I expected with result[0]['time'] ... 
Thanks a lot for your fast and perfect help to both of you!